# Вывод ошибок при регистрации

Tags: php

У меня код:

```
    session_start();
include_once("../lib/bd.php");
if (isset($_POST['vk-demo'])){
    if(empty($_POST['name']))  {
     die('Введите имя!');
}
   elseif(empty($_POST['lastname'])) { 
    die('Введите Фамилию!!');
}
   elseif(empty($_POST['password'])) {
    die("Введите пароль!");
}
    elseif (!preg_match("/\A(\w){6,20}\Z/", $_POST['password'])) {
    die ('6 символов pass');
}
   elseif(empty($_POST['password2'])) {
    die('Введите подтверждение пароля');
}
   elseif($_POST['password'] != $_POST['password2']) {
    die('Двое пароля не совпадают');
}
   elseif(empty($_POST['email'])) {
    die('ВВедите E-Mail!');
}
   elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/", $_POST['email'])) {
   die('Email eror');
}

else{
$password = $_POST['password'];
$mdPassword = md5($password);
$password2 = $_POST['password2'];
$password != $password2;
$email = $_POST['email'];
$rdate = date("d-m-Y в H:i");
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
```

Как сделать, чтобы вывод ошибок был в процессе регистрации, а не в новом окне? Ну, вы поняли, короче.

Comment: На клиенте проверяйте формы теми же регэкспами, что и на сервере на события: onchange, onkeypress. Ну или прикрутите какой-нибудь уже готовый валидатор, например Parsley: http://parsleyjs.org

Comment: @Devil_ru, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Это называется валидация на клиенте.

- Можно воспользоваться изъезженным вдоль и поперек [jquery-validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)
- Валидатор на базе [фреймворка AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) или [Backbone](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms)
- Существуют менее гибкий нативный html5 валидатор: [здесь](http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/article_1761.html) и [здесь](http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/article_1761.html). Имеет [проблемы с кроссбраузерностью](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation)
- Некоторые бэкенд-фреймворки позволяют [задействовать указанные в модели правила для проверки на стороне клиента](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/input-validation.md#%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-)

Answer (score 0):

Вешаете функцию валидации на форму отправки в атрибут onsubmit.

```
<form onsubmit="validation()">
</form>
```

И собственно реализуете эту функцию в JS